# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to do seller can delete the product

```
<form action="{{ route('product.destroy'}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('DELETE')}} 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
 </form>
```

this is in web.php

```
    Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index');//seller view all product

Route::get('/create', 'ProductController@create'); //seller create new product
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('product.store'); //store in database

Route::get('/edit/{id}','ProductController@edit'); // seller edit post
Route::put('edit/{id}','ProductController@update')->name('product.update'); //seller update

Route::delete('/{id}','ProductController@destroy')->name('product.destroy');//seller delete product
```

this is in ProductController

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product= Product::find($id);
        Storage::delete($product->image);
        $product->delete();

        return back()->withInfo('Product has been deleted');

    }
```

HELP me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing ID do it like

```
{{ route('product.destroy', $product->id)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try removing the post method of the form cause you specify another one and depend on which version you are using you can try @method('DELETE')

```
@method('DELETE')
```

it just more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ID in the route in form tags,

```
{{ route('product.destroy', $product->id)}}
```

Also

```
$product= Product::find($id);
    Storage::delete($product->image);
    $product->delete();
```

Check if their is a $product, then delete it, otherwise you'll get an error.